# Can I start developing a new java 8 web application that bridges to my old java 7 web application?

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, java-8

My problem is that I simply have an old web application developed using JDK1.7. Now I want to use the new technologies of Java 8 and Spring framework in any further development. 
The problem is that I cannot simply get rid of my old system. What are the approaches that you used? I heard somewhere about bridging web applications. Is that what I should be looking for?

Comment: Code that compiles and runs on Java 7 will compile and run perfectly fine on Java 8 (assuming you've adhered to the contracts specified in the Javadocs at the time).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can simply run the old app with the new JDK. If you are unlucky, small changes may be necessary, but it's virtually unheard of for "bridging" to be useful when updating JDKs.